# Android firebase NoClassDefFoundError error related inquiries

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, noclassdeffounderror, allatori

please contact the error below.

The log below is an error that remains in the Google Play Store Crash Report.

The error doesn't seem to happen on all phones,

It seems to occur intermittently on Android 8 to Android 9 devices.

It doesn't happen on my Android8 or Android 9 device.

The project is obfuscated with allatori.

If you have a similar error, please help.

---

**build.gradle**

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 41
        versionName "1.4.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        dexOptions {
            maxProcessCount 8
            preDexLibraries true
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha05'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha05'    
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.2.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.5.0'
}
```

---

**error**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.DaggerTransportRuntimeComponent$Builder.setApplicationContext(com.google.android.datatransport:transport-runtime@@2.2.0:105)
at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.DaggerTransportRuntimeComponent$Builder.setApplicationContext(com.google.android.datatransport:transport-runtime@@2.2.0:100)
at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.TransportRuntime.initialize(com.google.android.datatransport:transport-runtime@@2.2.0:77)
at com.google.firebase.datatransport.TransportRegistrar.lambda$getComponents$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-datatransport@@17.0.3:37)
  at com.google.firebase.datatransport.TransportRegistrar$$Lambda$1.create (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$new$0
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$1.get (Unknown Source:4)
  at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get
  at com.google.firebase.components.AbstractComponentContainer.get
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.get
  at com.google.firebase.components.RestrictedComponentContainer.get
  at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzl.create
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$new$0
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$1.get (Unknown Source:4)
  at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.initializeEagerComponents
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp
  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:1940)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:1915)
  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:6682)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:6229)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6144)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200 (ActivityThread.java:235)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1768)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6990)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1445)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
```

---

Comment: I have same error! Cant find the solution!!! :( It occurr only in some devices Android 8.1. App crash after splash is displayed. "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.TransportRuntime"

Comment: This class DaggerTransportRuntimeComponent$Builder is available in this [repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.datatransport/transport-runtime/2.2.0). As per your stacktrace, try adding this dependency `implementation 'com.google.android.datatransport:transport-runtime:2.2.0'`.

Comment: At some point, after updating the firebase bom library, the error disappeared...